# Typescript: Object has different keys, same types - How do you avoid redefining the whole object in an interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface with different keys that all accept the same enum values. I have defined a type these enum values called bloodType. Can I somehow skip defining the interface and simply state that all object keys must match the type when I define my object?

```js
/** Defining types that will go into the interface */
type bloodType = {
  | "typeA"
  | "typeB"
  | "typeO"
};

/** Defining the interface */
interface IPopulation {
  "Bobby": bloodType,
  "Jimmy": bloodType,
  "Sandra": bloodType,
  "Angel": bloodType,
  "JimmyJohn": bloodType,
}

/** The actual object using the interface */
const population:IPopulation = {
  "Bobby": "typeA",
  "Jimmy": "typeB",
  "Sandra": "typeB",
  "Angel": "typeO",
  "JimmyJohn": "typeA",
}
```

can I somehow skip defining the interface and just do...

```js
type bloodType = {
  | "typeA"
  | "typeB"
  | "typeO"
};

/** Is there some sort of shortcut like this */
const population = {
  "Bobby": "typeA",
  "Jimmy": "typeB",
  "Sandra": "typeB",
  "Angel": "typeO",
  "JimmyJohn": "typeA",
}: {string: bloodType || {}}; // <- this obv doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
type BloodType = 'typeA' | 'typeB' | 'typeO';

interface IPopulation {
  [key: string]: BloodType;
}
```